# How can I find out when a server will automatically restart "today"?

Tags: windows-server-2012, automatic-updates

When I logged on to a Windows Server 2012 today I saw the message (in red on the logon screen) "Your Computer will restart today to finish installing important updates".

I like to know exactly what time the server will automatically restart. Because in the moment (18:55) everybody is working on that server. If the server restarts automatically at i.e. 23:00 that would be ok. But if the server restarts "today" in 5 minutes that would be bad.

How can I find out when it will restart automatically?
And in case that is impossible to find out: How can I set my own time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/827417/how-to-determine-exact-date-time-of-windows-update-planned-restart on superuser